# Why does the page reload when using document.location in content script of a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

```
var location = document.location;
```

This is the first line of the content script of my chrome extension which causes
a page reload. Is this expected behavior ? I couldn't find any mention of this in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in global scope (and I have a hunch you are), then there are no local variables, and `var` does nothing. Thus, `location` is equal to `this.location`, and `this == window`... you can see where that's going. Try it in your console: `var location = "http://example.com"`; or, for a less graphic example, `var foo = 17; console.log(window.foo);`

(Note: I am not 100% sure, since it's been a while I wrote a Chrome extension and don't know for a fact you are in a global context there; but it is the only explanation that fits the facts that I can think of.)

To fix it, either change the name of your variable, or better yet, introduce a non-global context; e.g.:

```
(function() {
  var location = window.location; // does not blow up
})();
```

or equivalently

```
function pleaseDontBlowUp() {
  var location = window.location; // does not blow up
}
pleaseDontBlowUp();
```